# Unknown term in computation

Tags: combinatorics

An example from my textbook:

$$ ({1-x})^{-\tfrac{1}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{-\tfrac{1}{2}\choose k}(-1)^kx^k$$

Where does the $$ (-1)^k $$ come from? I just can't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct application of the binomial theorem is
$$
   (1 + z)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{k} z^k.
$$
Setting $z = -x$, we get
$$
   (1 - x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{k} (-x)^k = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{k} (-1)^k x^k.
$$
Note that $\binom{-1/2}{k}$ will itself alternate in sign, so $(-1)^k \binom{-1/2}{k}$ is another way to write $\left|\binom{-1/2}{k}\right|$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!